# how do i round/trucate a number without using methods like math.round or %3f?

Tags: java

So far I need to round a number that I inputted and get it to 3 decimal places without those methods.

```
    if(number !=(int)number){           
        number*=1000;      
        number=(int)number;  
        number=(double)number; 
        number/=1000;  
        System.out.println("-"+ number);         
    }
    if(number ==(int)number){       
        System.out.println("-"+ number + "00");
    }
```

With that above, it will work for any input except the ones with 2 decimal places, like 12.34 . 
How do I make it work if i type 12.34 and displays 12.340?

Comment: I don't really understand, you just want to append a 0 to the printout? Of course you can't append a 0 to the number itself.

Comment: Truncate is not the same as round!

Comment: what is your expected output if `number = 123.456789f` ?

Comment: it would be like 123.456

Comment: @user2923875 ohh well in that case I have updated my answer for that case also

Answer (score 0):

you can use printf method like this:

```
System.out.printf("result = %.3f",number);
```

**EDIT** ( without using `printf` format specifiers)

```
void floatTruncate(float val){
        float a = val;
        String result = a + "";

        int index = result.indexOf(".");
        int zeroes = result.length() - 1 - index;

        zeroes = 3 - zeroes;

        for (int i = 1; i <= zeroes && zeroes < 3; i++) {
            result = result + "0";
        }

        System.out.println("new result = " + result);

}
```

---

**EDIT 2:** ( if you want to keep only 3 decimal places if your input is is like `number = 22.34567f` and you want output as `22.345` then use this one

```
     void floatTruncate(float val) {
            float a = val;
            String result = a + "";

            int index = result.indexOf(".");
            int zeroes = result.length() - 1 - index;

//use this logic if ur logic is to keep only 3 decimal places 
            if(zeroes>3){
                result = result.substring(0, index+4);
            }
            zeroes = 3 - zeroes;

            for (int i = 1; i <= zeroes && zeroes < 3; i++) {
                result = result + "0";
            }

            System.out.println("new result = " + result);
        }
```

---

**sample outputs**

```
a = 22.3f -> 22.300
a = 22.34f -> 22.340
a = 22.345f -> 22.345
a = 22.34567f -> 22.345
```

Comment: Note that the OP's question is "without using methods like … %3f".

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this (truncates number):

```
number *= 1000.0;
if (((int) number) % 100 == 0) {
    System.out.println((number / 1000.0) + "00");
} else if (((int) number) % 10 == 0) {
    System.out.println((number / 1000.0) + "0");
} else {
    System.out.println(number / 1000.0);
}
```

Comment: is there a way to convert this using only if statements?

Answer (score 0):

What about this? Works for the given inputs

```
public static String truncate(Double a, int digits) {
    String[] values = a.toString().split("\\.");
    String integer = values[0];
    String decimal = values[1];


    if (decimal.length() < digits) {
        int n = digits - decimal.length();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            decimal += "0";
        }
        return integer + "." + decimal;
    }
    return integer + "." + decimal.substring(0, digits);

}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(truncate(1.0, 7));
    System.out.println(truncate(1.23719273, 4));
    System.out.println(truncate(1d, 1));
}
```

Out

```
1.0000000
1.2371
1.0
```